# How can I use the same tokens in different lexer modes in Antlr?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexer

I have an SQL Antlr4-based lexer that is also parsing specific tags from SQL comments:

```
OPEN_COMMENT: '/*' -> mode(COMMENT);
mode COMMENT;
NAME_TAG  :  '@name';
CLOSE_COMMENT: '*/' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
```

This lexer is able to read the following:

```
/* @name GetAllUsers */
```

However, I also want to be able to read line comments:

```
-- @name @GetAllUsers
```

I cannot use the same mode, because CLOSE_COMMENT should work differently: it should be `*/` for the block comment and `\n` for line comment. However, I want the parser to get the same tokens regardless of whether it is a line or block comment.

How can I implement this? Or may be using lexer modes is not the right approach for this at all?

(For the purpose of this question, I have trimmed the code to only necessary parts, so it would be easier to read and reason about. You can find the whole code in question [here](https://github.com/adelsz/pgtyped/blob/master/packages/query/src/loader/sql/grammar/SQLLexer.g4).)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to duplicate some things into 2 different modes. You could define common tokens, like the `NAME` token inside the grammar's `tokens { ... }` block so that it can be shared in both modes.

A quick demo:

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

tokens {
  NAME
}

ID
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;

LINE_COMMENT_START
 : '--' -> skip, mode(LINE_COMMENT_MODE)
 ;

BLOCK_COMMENT_START
 : '/*' -> skip, mode(BLOCK_COMMENT_MODE)
 ;

mode LINE_COMMENT_MODE;

  LINE_COMMENT_MODE_ID
   : ID -> type(ID)
   ;

  LINE_COMMENT_NAME
   : '@name' -> type(NAME)
   ;

  LINE_COMMENT_END
   : [\r\n]+ -> skip, mode(DEFAULT_MODE)
   ;

  LINE_COMMENT_OTHER
   : . -> skip
   ;

mode BLOCK_COMMENT_MODE;

  BLOCK_COMMENT_MODE_ID
   : ID -> type(ID)
   ;

  BLOCK_COMMENT_NAME
   : '@name' -> type(NAME)
   ;

  BLOCK_COMMENT_END
   : '*/' -> skip, mode(DEFAULT_MODE)
   ;

  BLOCK_COMMENT_OTHER
   : . -> skip
   ;
```

If you tokenize the input:

```sql
-- @name GetAllUsers
/* @name GetAllUsers */
```

you'd hget the following tokens:

```
NAME                      `@name`
ID                        `GetAllUsers`
NAME                      `@name`
ID                        `GetAllUsers`
```